# Grails dependency generation fails (ivy, Windows 7)

Tags: eclipse, grails, ivy, vmware-fusion

I have a problem getting a Grails eclipse project compiled. I am running Mac OS/X (Lions), but use Grails on Windows 7 in a VMware session as I have to interface to a Windows application.

The dependency generation fails with the following error:

```
Command terminated with an error code (see details for output)
------System.out:-----------
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script Compile: \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\.grails\ivy-     cache\resolved-org.grails.internal-petclinic-0.1.xml (The system cannot find the path specified) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
------System.err:-----------
```

The problem is that the directory "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders" does not exist and will never exist. I have tried to change the HOME, USER_HOME environment variables and even added a -Duser.home=c:\users\jm to the JVM settings, but I cannot change the temporary directory which is needed for the Grails build.

Does anyone know a trick to tell Grails/Ivy to use a different directory to work in?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, this helped:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Dgrails.work.dir=/usr/local/share/grails -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/usr/local/share/ivy"
```

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution in: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html

Comment: @JaapMulder you can give a more detailed answer to your own question and accept it. That way other users with the same problem can directly find a solution.